# C - Ways to display information on terminal quicker

Tags: c, terminal, console, printf

So I'm trying to display a *game-board* on my terminal and have players type in their next move (in my case 4-in-a-row). Each time the player makes their input, I'm drawing the board again.

[image: Player 'O' won! Well, player 'X' did play badly.]

Unfortunately, when inserting those walls and game pieces with each character individually, you can basically see how my slow computer displays each character one by one.

**To simplify things here, I'll pretend that I only want to display a large list of characters.** I already have most of the logic and inputs working, so I'm just looking for optimizations.

---

So this was my **first approach**. Just go through the loop and print it one by one.

```
// Rows
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    // Columns
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {

        // Note: to keep evererything neatly in-line, I'll just use if-statements
        if((y % 3) == 0) printf(" ");
        if((y % 3) == 1) printf("X");
        if((y % 3) == 2) printf("O");

    }
    printf("\n");  // Add line-break at the end
}
```

So my guess is that each time I'm calling `printf`, the computer analyzes and edits the string accordingly before printing it on my screen. Which probably is the reason why it's so slow. (please correct me if I'm wrong).

---

As a **second approach**, I tried to save all the letters inside a char array before printing it.

```
char text[500]; // Note: In my program I don't know how long the text is.
int index = 0;

// Rows
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    // Columns
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {

        if((y % 3) == 0) text[index] = ' '; // Set text index accordingly
        if((y % 3) == 1) text[index] = 'X';
        if((y % 3) == 2) text[index] = 'O';
        index++; // Increase index

    }
    text[index] = '\n';  // Add line-break
    index++;
}
text[index] = '\0'; // End of string
printf(text);
```

Though a little overwhelming at first, this code works perfectally for me and actually manages to print the string **a lot, lot** faster.

The problem with this is that **(1)** you quickly lose track of your index (so debugging is a real pain) and that **(2)** you have to live with the fear that your text will be longer than 500 characters (or that you only needed 100 and wasted a lot of free-space).

My question now is: **Are there any fast and more consistent ways to display information on your terminal screen?** Instead of displaying the game-board each round, could I also just delete the last few characters until I get to the piece that needs to be edited? Could I also freeze the screen until the content is ready?

For those interested, here's (almost) my full C-Code: http://pastebin.com/Emffgsdd

Comment: Use the `curses` library for this.

Comment: Have you considered using the [*ncurses*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library?

Comment: @Linnus Alright, I'll look into it!

Comment: @lurker Never heard of it before. I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, instead of redrawing everything, everytime, you could only draw the changes (like new play elements on the game). The challenge is keeping track of the screen state.

One well known terminal library that takes care of most of those issues is [NCURSES](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). There is a good [online book](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html) by Eric Raymond.